# WebStorm 10: list of typescript community stubs truncated

Tags: node.js, webstorm, should.js

I'm using Should.js and I'd like to get some auto-completion for it. Unfortunately WebStorm is not showing all the TypeScript community stubs. Just like in the DefinitelyTyped GitHub page the list is truncated to show the first 1000 files only. At this moment libraries that have a name starting with the letter 'S' and beyond will not show up.

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I work around this?

Use [v11 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP) builds -- this limitation is [bypassed/fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18181) there.

Alternatively -- download file(s) from github and manage such libraries manually.

Comment: Good to hear it's fixed! The next release will happen somewhere around October so I think I'll just wait for that.